# Is it ok to put methods/fields to base class that will only be used by some of the derived classes

Tags: class, inheritance, architecture, software-design

This is a bit of a generic software design question. Suppose you have a base class and lots of classes that derive from it (around 10).

There is some common functionality that is being shared between some of the classes (3-4 of derived classes need it). Basically a field for a UI control, an abstract method to create a UI control and the common code that uses the abstract method to recycle the UI piece (8-9 lines of code) using the abstract method. Something like this:

```
class BaseClass {
    ...

    protected UIControl control;

    protected abstract UIControl CreateUI();

    protected void RecycleUI() {
        if (/* some condition is met */) {
            if (this.control != null) {
                control.Dispose();
            }
            this.control = this.CreateUI();
            this.AddToUITree(control);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Do you think it is OK to put this to base class instead of replicating the code in derived classes.

Drawback is that this piece of code is only used for some of the base classes and completely irrelevant for the other classes.

One alternative is to create an intermediate class that derives from BaseClass and use it as the base to the ones that need the functionality. I felt like creating a derived class for a couple line of code for a very specific purpose felt heavy. It doesn't feel like it is worth interrupting the inheritance tree for this. We try to keep the hierarchy as simple as possible so that it is easy to follow and understand the inheritance tree. Maybe if this was C++ where multiple inheritance is an option, it wouldn't be a big issue but multiple inheritance is not available.

Another option is to create a utility method and an interface to create/update the UI control:

```
interface UIContainer {
    UIControl CreateUIControl();

    UIControl GetUIControl();

    void SetUIControl(UIControl control);
}

class UIControlUtil {
    public void RecycleUI(UIContainer container) {
        if (/* some condition is met */) {
            if (container.GetUIControl() != null) {
                container.GetUIControl().Dispose();
            }
            UIControl control = container.CreateUI();
            container.SetUIControl(control);
            container.AddToUITree(control);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like this option because it bleeds UI logic externally which is less secure as its UI state can be manipulated externally. Also derived classes have to implement getter/setter now. One advantage is that there is another class outside of the aforementioned inheritance tree and it needs this functionality and it can use this utility function as well.

Do you have any other suggestions? Should I just suppress the urges that brew inside me to have common code not repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One alternative is to create an intermediate class that derives from
>   BaseClass and use it as the base to the ones that need the
>   functionality.

Well, this is what I thought is the most appropriate. But it depends. The main question here is the following: are objects, that require UI recycling and really different from those, that do not? If they are really different, you have to create a new base class for them. If difference is really negligible, I think it's ok to leave things in a base class.

Do not forget about [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

> We try to keep the hierarchy as simple as possible so that it is easy
>   to follow and understand the inheritance tree

I think more important here is to keep things not only simple, but also close to your real world things so that modeling new entities would be easy. Seeming easiness now may cause real troubles in the future.

Comment: > are objects, that require UI recycling and really different from those, that do not?

They're not too different apart from this UI recycling. They do not have such functionality.

I ended up leaving the code replicated for now mostly because logic itself is very simple and mostly likely it won't require maintenance going forward.

Good point about LSP though.

Comment: @nrydn Glad you solved that one ;) Thanks for a good question.